# Keyword not supported Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce

I am working on a project that is on .NET Framework 4 and when I enter the `Update-Database` command in the package manager console, I encounter this error:

> Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'

My connection string in `app.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DocsControlDBConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DocsControl_DB;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And my `DbContext`:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context() : base("DocsControlDBConnectionString")
    { 
    }

    public DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ActivityTime> ActivityTimes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Approver> Approvers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomFormat> CustomFormats { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Delete> Deletes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DocumentName> DocumentNames { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EditDate> EditDates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EditNumber> EditNumbers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PDFFile> PDFFiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Producer> Producers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.Type> Types { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WordFile> WordFiles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Please guide me

Comment: As a look at [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/) for SQL Server Compact Edition would easily reveal - the SQL Server CE connections are made to a **file** ( `.sdf`) which **is** the database - you cannot additionally specify an "initial catalog" - the file itself already is the database you're connecting to. Look at that site - either you're not really using SQL Server **CE** - then your `provider` spec is wrong - or you *are* using SQL Server CE, then your connection string is just plain wrong....

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to use SQL Server Express Edition (which is real SQL Server) instead of the deprecated SQL Server Compact Edition (which is not real SQL Server)?

Comment: @marc_s The database has not been created yet and I want it to be created with the `Update-Database` command

Comment: As I said - the `providerName` and `connectionString` values don't match - **either** you really want SQL Server CE - then you need to change the connection string; **or** your connection string is correct, but then you're referencing a *real* SQL Server (Express, Web, Developer, Standard, Enterprise edition) and then you need to change your `providerName` setting. Whether the database exists or not is totally irrelevant in this context right now

Comment: I understand what you said, thank you, but what should I set the value of the provider name?